# OpenCV - how to crop out the rear of a truck in a scene?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

Currently I'm working with a large number of images that look roughly like this:

[image]

I'd like to crop out the back of the truck like this:

[image]

Here are some of the things I'm up against that make this challenging:

- the truck can be any color
- the scene can be day or night
- the background can vary substantially (trees, bushes, road, sky,
  etc.)

I have the following working in my favor:

- the truck will always fill up most of the image
- the camera resolution and quality will be at least as good as in this
  example image
- if at night, the rear of the truck will be relatively well lit with a
  flood light or similar

So far I'm having a difficult time getting much to work.  Here are some of the things that I've tried:

- Gaussian bluring / eroding / dilating / opening / closing (both
  before and after getting to a single channel, see next bullet points)
- converting to grayscale
- breaking out the B, G, R channels
- breaking out the H, S, V channels
- breaking out the L, A, B channels
- on each of the above 10 channels I've tried:
- cv::threshold()
- cv::adaptiveThreshold()
- cv::Canny()
- cv::floodFill()
- cv::watershed()

None of these has produced a result that seems promising.

Can anybody offer any alternative suggestions?  A different direction?  Perhaps I'm missing another helpful pre-processing step?  I'm not sure where to go next.

Comment: Are there specific features on the back of the truck, that you can register? For example the company logo, or the number on the left?

Comment: Unfortunately no, the trailer can be for any one of many companies.  The logos could be different and the numbers can be anywhere.

Comment: Sounds like a job for machine learning.

Comment: It would be nice if you could post a few more sample images ( To get an idea of the variety of images ).

Comment: Have you tried any deep learning object detection API's to solve this problem? Should be pretty quick to compare the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tried something exactly like this in the past.

Setting threshold and detecting lines will not work for all images since they can highly vary with lighting, background etc.

Solution:

Go for deep learning models.
Train your model with around 1000 images initially. With input as images and output as coordinates of the cropped region.

Since as an output you are going to get coordinates of a rectangle. Use these coordinates to crop the region out.
check [this](https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/object_localization_and_detection.html) for further details.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have no idea why some wanker downvoted your response.  The more I think about it, the variability in the images is enough that a deep learning approach seems necessary.  I think I'll try getting TensorFlow to work on this and see what I can come up with.  That link was very helpful as well.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Glad you found that helpful

Comment: This is a good example for an actually helpful answer that does not contain code. There is a trend on SO to down-vote answers without code, I hope the moderators can pay attention to this.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to perform Hough Line Detection(cv::HoughLines) after performing Canny Edge detection, and select the largest rectangle that you can form using the near horizontal and vertical lines that are detected.

While thresholding based approaches might work on some images, they ignore high level information like the rectangular shape of the container's back.

[This page](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_lines/hough_lines.html) has a working example that can be a starting point.

I will edit the question if you need more details.

Comment: HoughLines() and HoughLinesP() both take a binary image, so I would have to convert to one channel one of the ways I mentioned in my post and then thresh to a binary image to use either of these.  As janu777 mentioned there is potentially so much variability in the images that getting 4 clean, consistent lines would be impossible.  Perhaps I should have clarified this further in my original post.

Comment: To get Hough lines, you need a binary image but it is not created by thresholding. It is best created using Canny edge detection. Edge detection is more robust to lighting variations than thresholding. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks, but I already mentioned in the original post that I tried cv::threshold, cv::adaptiveThreshold, and cv::Canny()

Answer (score 0):

First comment, do you really need to cut it automatically ?

If your large number of image is less than 10000 then you should do it by hand.
If the number is bigger than that and can be increased overtime, them you should build the software.

Secondly, with your conditions, simple threshold will never work. It is too complex for a simple threshold to handle it .

In my opinions,  the easiest approach is first segment your image, then cut off the segmentation which has biggest area. 
You also could use more complex approach like training a detector to detect truck. (SSD is currently the best object detector)

Comment: Yes, I need to crop the truck out automatically, the images will be coming from a video camera as trucks pass (to avoid mentioning anything company specific I would rather not elaborate on this).  Thanks for the suggestion, it seems a deep learning approach will be necessary.